# Choice of Music (Wordplay)

Tags: wordplay

A boy tries to talk to his ex after class at school. However, she just puts on some music and shuns him instead, leaving him to wonder why.

What type of music is she listening to, and why?

**HINT 1**

> What sort of classes would you attend at school?

**HINT 2**

> Some deliberate word choices were made for their "sounds like" functionality. (Specifically three words).

**HINT 3**

> The answers to the above two hints are 1) Maths, and 2) Ex, Shun, and Why.

Comment: Any and all feedback on how I might improve the puzzle is welcome! I'm new to puzzle-craft and am happy to have some constructive criticism thrown my way.

Comment: You should 'mention' that this question is horrible. Also, at the same time, get 100 upvotes. That would certainly make your puzzle look better. Being serious, though, your question is actually really good! Welcome to Puzzling.SE!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

She is listening to

> Funk music

Because

> In Math class we can see X's (Ex), Y's (Why) and Functions (sounds like Funk-Shuns)

Answer (score 2):

Is she listening to

> BAND music, from her music/band class at school....because he’s BANNED from her life?? (I’ll see myself out....)

Comment: I like the thinking behind this, but unfortunately it is not that type of music.
There are several layers to this puzzle, and knowing the lesson is itself a hint to figuring out the solution.